# Find the most frequent value in a column and take a subset of that

Tags: r

I have the following dataset.

```
Num              Day              Value
1111             Thursday         2
2222             Thursday         2
3333             Thursday         3
1111             Monday           3
1111             Tuesday          3
1111             Wednesday        3
1111             Friday           4
1111             Saturday         5
1111             Sunday           6
2222             Thursday         6
```

We can get the highest occuring value in column `value` by using the following command: `tail(names(sort(table(data$value))), 1)`

I dynamically need to get the subset of the data containing only this highest occurring value.

So the output I would need is:

```
Num              Day              Value
3333             Thursday         3
1111             Monday           3
1111             Tuesday          3
1111             Wednesday        3
```

Comment: I would use `data[data$Value==as.numeric(names(which.max(table(data$Value)))),]`. Using `tail` and `sort` is a rather complicated way to get the max count - I would use `which.max` here. Also, `names` returns a character vector. The `==` comparison between integer and character seems to work but I think it would be better to explicitly convert to `numeric`. Finally, I try to avoid using `subset` where possible (several posts here on SO explain why `subset` can be tricky).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `subset`

```
 indx <- tail(names(sort(table(df1$Value))),1)
 subset(df1, Value==indx)
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
   group_by(Value) %>% 
   mutate(N=n()) %>%
   ungroup() %>% 
   filter(N==max(N))
```

Or

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df1)[, N:=.N, Value][N==max(N)][, N:=NULL]
```

Comment: any reason to use `[,N:=NULL]` over `[,!"N",with=F]` besides style?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I think both can be used, `:=` may be a bit faster (not tested)

Comment: @akrun Ran some tests and confirm it's always faster, especially as the number of columns in `.SD` increases (which makes sense--your way should be basically independent of the number of columns in the table); with 10 other columns, it's about 20% faster (consistently up to 100000 rows), but with 500 to 1000 columns, your way is up to 60% faster.